# UITableViewController Files

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Following a tutorial exactly, I created files that extend UITableViewController. The problem is that his uitableviewcontroller.m files is filled with pre written code (like the viewDidLoad), while mine is completely blank! Both our uitableviewcontroller.h files all have the code of

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ChemTable : UITableViewController
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *Chemarray;


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For learning purpose the auto-generated method are of least use(its perfectly ok even if You remove it). even you can create app without them....."viewDidLoad" is the one very necessary method that runs when the view is loaded, but when you go for real apps you will surely use some of auto-generated methods.

Extra -->I think you also also should see this:
    ViewDidLoad - Called when you create the class and load from xib. Great for initial setup and one-time-only work

```
ViewWillAppear - Called right before your view appears, good for hiding/showing fields or any operations that you want to happen every time before the view is visible. Because you might be going back and forth between views, this will be called every time your view is about to appear on the screen

ViewDidAppear - Called after the view appears - great place to start an animations or the loading of external data from an API.

ViewWill/DidDisappear - Same idea as the WillAppear.

ViewDidUnload/Dispose - Available to you, but usually not necessary in Monotouch. In objective-c, this is where you do your cleanup and release of stuff, but this is handled automatically so not much you really need to do here.
```